# Guessing HTML vs Plain Text and Entity Reference Character in HTML

Tags: python, html, escaping

Input supplied as Text

```
# Python 2.7
>>> bs4.BeautifulSoup("H&W Insurance")
<html><body><p>H&amp;W Insurance</p></body></html>

# Python 3.5.2
>>> import lxml.html
>>> h = lxml.html.fromstring("H&W Insurance")
>>> lxml.html.tostring(h)
b'<p>H&amp;W Insurance</p>'
```

`BeautifulSoup` and `lxml` has escaped my input correctly. But how did it guess that I typed a Text and not HTML? Is there any standard algorithm for that, it doesn't seem really trivial to me.

Input supplied as HTML

```
# Python 2.7
>>> bs4.BeautifulSoup("<html>H&W Insurance<html>")
<html><body><p>H&amp;W Insurance</p></body></html>

# Python 3.5.2
>>> h = lxml.html.fromstring("<html>H&W Insurance</html>")
>>> lxml.html.tostring(h)
b'<html><body><p>H&amp;W Insurance</p></body></html>'
```

Why is `&` getting converted to `&amp;`. Couldn't that have been an HTML Entity Reference `&` character in the input or has BeautifulSoup auto-corrected that because`&W` has no meaning in HTML so it has to be `&amp;`?

Comment: No, the string `H&W` is valid HTML. It can't be a character reference because character references are terminated by a semicolon. The HTML5 parsing algorithm prescribes what a parser should do after seeing a `&`: [*Attempt to consume a character reference, with no additional allowed character. If nothing is returned, emit a U+0026 AMPERSAND character (&) token.*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-reference-in-data-state)

Comment: Thanks @amon you could have answered made it an answer. Does anyone think this should this be moved to StackOverflow? Where does question belong?